# Node.js: adding process.nextTick() call to top-level code affects setTimeout() and setImmediate() order

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, settimeout, event-loop, libuv

As explained on the official guides (https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#setimmediate-vs-settimeout), if I run the following snippet,  I get different order for logs, sometimes `immediate` first, and sometimes `timeout` first, i.e. the order is *non-deterministic*:

```js
setImmediate(() => {
  console.log("immediate");
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("timeout");
}, 0);
```

Output:

```
> node index.js
immediate
timeout

> node index.js
immediate
timeout

> node index.js
timeout
immediate
```

However, if I add the `process.nextTick()` call to the mix, unexpectedly, the order for `timeout` and `immediate` is fixed (`timeout` is always printed before `immediate`):

```js
setImmediate(() => {
  console.log("immediate");
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("timeout");
}, 0);

process.nextTick(() => {
  console.log("next tick");
});
```

Output:

```
> node index.js
next tick
timeout
immediate

> node index.js
next tick
timeout
immediate


> node index.js
next tick
timeout
immediate
```

I could not understand how does `process.nextTick()` affect the order of `timeout` and `immediate`. Can someone help me understand what is happening internally here?

Comment: The way we bootstrap is a bit confusing like that. Code that runs synchronously when modules bootstrap is special in terms of timing. I'll see if this is documented. Note we make no guarantees regarding the ordering of setTimeout/setImmediate and what executes first.

Comment: Are you interested in a technical "this is where it happens in the Node.js code" or a guarantee one "These are the guarantees we make about timers and immediates" ?

Comment: If you use the ESM module system (name your file `.mjs` or set "type": "module" in your package.json) node bootstraps asynchronously which should align the behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that *the order in which the two timers are executed is non-deterministic*, but I'm curious why adding process.nextTick() aligns the order? @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: "aligns" is a bit of a fallacy, there is some discussion here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15081 - there are two things here: the fact the synchronous bootstrap of Node.js (running code outside a task changes behaviour) and the fact the order of setImmediate/setTimeout is not guaranteed. You can even get `setTimeout(fn, 100)` to run before a `setImmediate` in certain situations (happened to me last week!)